# iOS: Adding data to a BLE characteristic throwing error asking for read-only characteristic

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS BLE service that advertises and can be connected to, but now I want to add a characteristic to the peripheral. I figured I'd just add a new NSData object to the value property for creating the characteristic, but whenever I call addService on the peripheral manager, I get this error:

```
2015-09-24 09:02:59.456 peripheral[459:27589] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Characteristics with cached values must be read-only'
```

My method for adding the characteristic looks like this:

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral{
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        _shareService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:_serviceUUID primary:YES];
        _notifyUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"F098FDEF-B82C-43F1-8BFB-18757743BA10"];
        _notificationCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:_notifyUUID
                                                                         properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
                                                                              value:[@"Some Data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]
                                                                        permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

        [_shareService setCharacteristics:@[_notificationCharacteristic]];

        [_pMgr addService:_shareService];

        [self startAdvertising];

    }
}
```

though when I change the value item to be nil, it advertises fine again. I'm sure there's something simple that I'm missing, but I'm still fairly new with iOS so any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of the `CBMutableCharacteristic` init method -

> value - The characteristic value to be cached. If nil, the value is
>   dynamic and will be requested on demand.

This means if you specify a non-nil value when you create the `CBMutableCharacteristic` then it is a 'cached characteristic' and as the error message says, you cannot change the value later. Specify `nil` when you create the `CBMutableCharacteristic`- You supply the value when requested in the `didReceiveReadRequest` `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` method.

Comment: I'll play around with this a bit. Still not seeing data coming back with that method, but hopefully I can get it working here pretty soon.